# Direct Open Form view window instead of Summary window on Calendar Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, calendar, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I Want to open direct form view instead on Summary window on calendar. So, how to open direct form view when click on calendar view?

I use *web_calendar* module *(widgets.js file)* as a reference.

I tried with following code:

```
var self = this;
    this._super(parent, {
        title: this.get_title(),
        size: 'small',
        buttons: this._buttons ? [
            {text: _t("Create"), classes: 'btn-primary', click: function () {
                if (!self.quick_add()) {
                    self.focus();
                }
            }},
            {text: _t("Edit"), click: function () {
                self.slow_add();
            }},
            {text: _t("Cancel"), close: true},
        ] : [],
        $content: QWeb.render('CalendarView.quick_create', {widged: this})
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on Odoo 11 and to go from calendar directly to form view without summary window, the only thing I had to do is setting the attribute quick_add="False" in the xml calendar tag. I could imagine this also works on earlier Odoo versions but don't know.

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <calendar ... quick_add="False">
        <field name="name"/>
    </calendar>
</field>
```